# Implementing iterators and const_iterators

Tags: c++, listiterator, const-iterator

I'm having an issue with compiling regarding a doubly linked list class with nested iterator and const_iterator classes inside.

I'm new to using template syntax and it's kind of become a bit of a nightmare. Right now I seem to be getting an error on each of my functions and a linker error at the end. This makes me feel like there is something wrong with my header, or the inclusion of the header, or something to do with the signatures of the functions.

A sample of my header is :

```
class const_iterator {
    friend RecentList;
    Node* curr_;
    const_iterator(Node* p);
public:
    const_iterator();
    const_iterator operator++() const;
```

The corresponding implementation is:

```
template <typename T>
   RecentList<T>::const_iterator::const_iterator(){
    curr_=nullptr;
}

template <typename T>
RecentList<T>::const_iterator::const_iterator(Node* p){
    curr_=p;
}

template <typename T>
typename RecentList<T>::const_iterator RecentList<T>::const_iterator::operator++() const{
    //++it
    curr_ = curr_->next_;
    return *this;
}
```

When I try to compile though, it gives me 42 errors like:

"RecentList::const_iterator::operator++(int) const", referenced from:

with the linker error at the end.

Also the reason why the template stuff is there is because the list class uses templates. Xcode doesn't like it when I don't include that syntax.

Where should I look to correct the issue?

Comment: Sounds like you only implemented preincrement and then tried to use postincrement.

Comment: Are the implementations declared in the header file?

Comment: Why are you implementing a linked list manually instead of using `std::list`?